# Unable to Access the internet on Windows, but can with Ubuntu (have dual-boot)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, internet-connection

My personal computer dual boots on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu. About 5-6 months ago, I stopped being able to access the internet whenever I booted via W7, but I still could, and can, with Ubuntu. After not being able to fix the problem, I just gave up, and have been continually booting up on Ubuntu.

I noticed that I could/can successfully ping sites from the command prompt on W7, just not use the internet normally, as stated above. I checked all of the proxy settings, and one is definitely not being used. I also disabled/un-installed all anti-viruses, firewalls, re-set TCP/IP, etc.

I can give whatever info that is needed.

Comment: When you're pinging sites, are you specifying a hostname, or an ip address directly?  I'm curious if you're just having a DNS related issue.

Comment: I'm just using a host name (i.e. www.yahoo.com). I THINK I tried once with an ip address, and it also worked, but am not sure. Will try now. Yeah, just successsfully pinged Yahoo's IP, so that is working.

Comment: It might help if you clarified what "normal Internet usage" you are trying, and what happens when you do. Do things just hang/timeout? Are you getting any error messages? Have you tried things other than browsers; e.g., `ftp` (either from the Command Prompt or Windows, whatever you have)? What is Windows Update showing? etc.

Comment: I will also add (forgot to mention) that in network settings, it does say that it is connected to the internet.

Comment: By normal, I mean any kind of internet usage, besides pinging sites and/or IP's via the command prompt. Browsers, applications that use the internet, etc. cannot access the internet in any way.

Comment: I think what @scott meant to ask whas to name specifics about what you've tried.  With browsers: was it Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer, Opera?  And did you check their application specific proxy settings, as not all utilize the system wide proxy settings?  On a separate matter, do you have Windows Firewall or any other firewall application running that may be blocking more traffic than it should be?

Comment: ... and, for example, what happens when you plug a numeric IP address into a browser? For that matter, as I asked before, exactly ***what happens*** when you try to surf the web with a browser? (Reread my first comment.) Also, have you tried mounting a network drive? ... running an email client (not using web-based email)? ... running Wireshark?

Comment: Asking the obvious but you have run the win7 network troubleshooter?

Answer (score 0):

I would leave this in a comment but not enough reputation to.

Try reinstalling the Win 7 ethernet/wireless drivers. We've had some weird issues in the past (especially with the laptops we deploy) where windows updates or software installs have caused multiple drivers/corrupted drivers which cause various issues.

Also, check what your default gateway/dns and dhcp or static IP addresses are by going to Network and Sharing Center ->Change Adapter Settings -> right-click properties -> IPv4 Properties. Maybe try comparing them to an ifconfig on your ubuntu machine?

Lastly, do you have a firewall - like Symantec, Norton, Windows firewall, etc - which you could look in to? Perhaps try temporarily disabling to see if that allows web access via the browser and then determining what in the config is blocking it.

Comment: Given that the OP "can successfully ping sites from the Command Prompt on W7", why do you suspect a problem at the driver level?

Comment: I updated the answer to include my reasoning for re-installing drivers.